# Is "date" header in response reliable for getting current datetime?

Tags: javascript, datetime, single-page-application

all. I am building a single page application and there's a case I need to know current datetime in my application.

I know it is not safe to use JavaScript Date object to get the current time because it relies on client, and there will be a problem if the client time is not correct.
So, I was looking for the other methods to get current time and came to my mind that getting current time from "date" response header might be safer.

Is it a good practice? Are there any better alternatives for this?

Comment: What response header do you mean? Where do you send this request?

Comment: Depends on who is setting the header and how accurate you need that information. ...

Comment: I prepare an empty file, and send a request to it from client. And in the response, the "Date" header in this form will be returned. And I mean I can use this Date header as a current datetime.

Comment: It does not need to be super accurate. Some seconds are acceptable.

Comment: It's the date on the server. If you trust the server's clock, it should be fine.

Comment: Ok. I am using amazon s3 + cloudfront, so the server's clock should be accurate. Thnak you for your response.